# Rebuilding my portfolio site from scratch in CraftCMS 3 and having an issue getting content to display

Tags: entry-query

I'm rebuilding my portfolio site in CraftCMS 3 and started building some VERY basic templates to test the sections and ensure everything is connecting properly before uploading a bunch of content and building all the more complicated elements in my templates. I have a layout template and a home page index template that extends this layout. The layout is just a basic HTML5 boilerplate from emmet and a block tag. The index page template has a headline pulled from a single and an entry query that will generate a list of portfolio pieces from a structure. Below is the code for this page in its current, basic state.

```
{% extends "_layouts/main" %}

{% block main %}

<h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>

{# Create an entry query #}
{% set portfolioGrid = craft.entries().section('portfolio').all() %}

{# Display the entries #}
<ul>
    {% for portfolioTile in portfolioGrid %}
    <li>{{ portfolioTile.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

{{ entry.title }} displays fine and the  tags are generated but the {% for %} loop isn't doing anything. I'm not getting any errors in the debug toolbar that I can see. The section name is correct. What else am I missing here? This should be a simple, straightforward query but it's blank.

Comment: The query looks fine. Does your `portfolio` section have any published content yet? Maybe you only have unpublished test content. Try dumping the result of the query to check what it's returning: `{% dd portfolioGrid %}`

Comment: Problem solved. The default now seems to save as a draft with a publish draft option in the toolbar to push the content live. Good to know about the dd tag though.

Answer (score 2):

Craft 3.5 (not sure when this occurred so maybe earlier) seems to default to a "save" draft"c option for new entries. You have to publish the draft before it can go live. All working now though.